# Spring Example "Securing a Web Application"

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is the Spring framework example titled "Securing a Web Application" (at http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) wrong?
  I've tried it line by line but the "Set up Spring Security" part (at http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial) does not work.

The gradle file downloaded with the source, with respect to the one published on the page, has this differences:

```
30d29
<     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
36c35
< }
---
> }
\ No newline at end of file
```

Is it correct or I've made some other error while working on this tutorial/guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error (see https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web/issues/18), now closed.